# Getting the current path from where a module is being called

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python module I built myself and it's located in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/my_module1`. In the module I have this:

```
class Class1(object); 
  def __init__(self, file_name):
    self.file_name = file_name # how can I get the full path of file_name?
```

How do I get the full of `file_name`? That is, if it's just a file name without a path, then append the current folder **from where the module is being called**. Otherwise, treat the file name as a full path.

```
# /users/me/my_test.py
  from module1 import Class1
  c = Class1('my_file1.txt') # it should become /users/me/my_file1.txt
  c1 = Class1('/some_other_path/my_file1.txt') # it should become /some_other_path/my_file1.txt/users/me/my_file1.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Sorry about that. I mis-read your question. All you need to do is pass `filename` so `os.path.abspath()`.

**Example:**

```
import os

filename = os.path.abspath(filename)
```

To cater for your 2nd case (*which I find quite weird*):

```
import os

if os.path.isabs(filenaem):
    filename os.path.join(
        os.path.join(
            filename,
            os.getcwd()
        ),
        os.path.basename(filename)
    )
```

Comment: **__file__ ** ===> 
'/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/module1/file1.py'

Comment: You don't understand the question.

Comment: **from where a module is being called**. Not the path of the module.

Comment: how can the caller's context be accessed from a function or method (without a means to modify it)?

Comment: if module2 uses module1 which path are you getting?